# image normalization and TPU

Tags: tensorflow, tpu, data-augmentation

I'm trying to incorporate image normalization in my keras model to run on Google's cloud TPU. Therefore I inserted a line into my code:

```
with strategy.scope():
     input_shape=(128,128,3)
     image_0 = Input(shape=input_shape)
     **image_1 = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image_0)**
     ...
```

There was nor error thrown, but according the documentation of google tf.image.per_image_standardization
is not a supported function. Does anybody know if it works anyhow, or does anybody have an idea how to check if it works?

Answer (score 0):

From the TensorFlow Model Garden reference for ResNet, the mean and standard deviation of a dataset is often calculated beforehand and each batch is standardized via mean subtract and dividing by the standard deviation. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/image_classification/preprocessing.py#L384-L387) for a reference (this uses ImageNet statistics).

I would suggest creating a separate script that calculates the mean and standardization and doing the same. Could you also point to the documentation where `tf.image.per_image_standardization` is not supported? I don't see why this wouldn't work, but you shouldn't apply it as a layer like in the provided code snippet. It should be in the data preprocessing pipeline like in the above reference.